# Confluent 4.1.0 ->KSQL : STREAM-TABLE join -> table data null

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

STEP 1:  Run the producer to create sample data

```
./bin/kafka-avro-console-producer \
         --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic stream-test-topic \
         --property schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081 \
         --property value.schema='{"type":"record","name":"dealRecord","fields":[{"name":"DEAL_ID","type":"string"},{"name":"DEAL_EXPENSE_CODE","type":"string"},{"name":"DEAL_BRANCH","type":"string"}]}'
```

Sample Data :

```
{"DEAL_ID":"deal002", "DEAL_EXPENSE_CODE":"EXP002", "DEAL_BRANCH":"AMSTERDAM"}
{"DEAL_ID":"deal003", "DEAL_EXPENSE_CODE":"EXP003", "DEAL_BRANCH":"AMSTERDAM"}
{"DEAL_ID":"deal004", "DEAL_EXPENSE_CODE":"EXP004", "DEAL_BRANCH":"AMSTERDAM"}
{"DEAL_ID":"deal005", "DEAL_EXPENSE_CODE":"EXP005", "DEAL_BRANCH":"AMSTERDAM"}
{"DEAL_ID":"deal006", "DEAL_EXPENSE_CODE":"EXP006", "DEAL_BRANCH":"AMSTERDAM"}
{"DEAL_ID":"deal007", "DEAL_EXPENSE_CODE":"EXP001", "DEAL_BRANCH":"AMSTERDAM"}
{"DEAL_ID":"deal008", "DEAL_EXPENSE_CODE":"EXP002", "DEAL_BRANCH":"AMSTERDAM"}
{"DEAL_ID":"deal009", "DEAL_EXPENSE_CODE":"EXP003", "DEAL_BRANCH":"AMSTERDAM"}
{"DEAL_ID":"deal010", "DEAL_EXPENSE_CODE":"EXP004", "DEAL_BRANCH":"AMSTERDAM"}
{"DEAL_ID":"deal011", "DEAL_EXPENSE_CODE":"EXP005", "DEAL_BRANCH":"AMSTERDAM"}
{"DEAL_ID":"deal012", "DEAL_EXPENSE_CODE":"EXP006", "DEAL_BRANCH":"AMSTERDAM"}
```

STEP 2: Open another terminal and run the consumer to test the data.

```
./bin/kafka-avro-console-consumer --topic stream-test-topic \
         --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
         --property schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081 \
         --from-beginning
```

STEP 3: Open another terminal and run the producer.

```
./bin/kafka-avro-console-producer \
         --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic expense-test-topic \
--property "parse.key=true" \
--property "key.separator=:" \
--property schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081 \
--property key.schema='"string"' \
         --property value.schema='{"type":"record","name":"dealRecord","fields":[{"name":"EXPENSE_CODE","type":"string"},{"name":"EXPENSE_DESC","type":"string"}]}'
```

Data:

```
"pk1":{"EXPENSE_CODE":"EXP001", "EXPENSE_DESC":"Regulatory Deposit"}
"pk2":{"EXPENSE_CODE":"EXP002", "EXPENSE_DESC":"ABC - Sofia"}
"pk3":{"EXPENSE_CODE":"EXP003", "EXPENSE_DESC":"Apple Corporation"}
"pk4":{"EXPENSE_CODE":"EXP004", "EXPENSE_DESC":"Confluent Europe"}
"pk5":{"EXPENSE_CODE":"EXP005", "EXPENSE_DESC":"Air India"}
"pk6":{"EXPENSE_CODE":"EXP006", "EXPENSE_DESC":"KLM International"}
```

STEP 4: Open another terminal and run the consumer

```
./bin/kafka-avro-console-consumer --topic expense-test-topic \
         --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
--property "parse.key=true" \
--property "key.separator=:" \
--property schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081 \
         --from-beginning
```

STEP 5: Login to KSQL client.

```
./bin/ksql http://localhost:8088
```

create following stream and table and run join query.

KSQL:

STREAM:

```
    CREATE STREAM SAMPLE_STREAM 
       (DEAL_ID VARCHAR, DEAL_EXPENSE_CODE varchar, DEAL_BRANCH VARCHAR) 
       WITH (kafka_topic='stream-test-topic',value_format='AVRO', key = 'DEAL_ID');
```

TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE SAMPLE_TABLE 
   (EXPENSE_CODE varchar, EXPENSE_DESC VARCHAR)
   WITH (kafka_topic='expense-test-topic',value_format='AVRO', key = 'EXPENSE_CODE');
```

FOLLOWING is the OUTPUT:

```
ksql> SELECT STREAM1.DEAL_EXPENSE_CODE, TABLE1.EXPENSE_DESC 
       from SAMPLE_STREAM STREAM1 LEFT JOIN SAMPLE_TABLE TABLE1 
       ON STREAM1.DEAL_EXPENSE_CODE = TABLE1.EXPENSE_CODE  
       WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 3 MINUTE) 
       GROUP BY STREAM1.DEAL_EXPENSE_CODE, TABLE1.EXPENSE_DESC;

EXP001 | null
EXP001 | null
EXP002 | null
EXP003 | null
EXP004 | null
EXP005 | null
EXP006 | null
EXP002 | null
EXP002 | null
```

Comment: Great question with steps to reproduce, I have just edited for formatting and to change the ports to the standard ones for others who want to run it.

Comment: Just a side note. If you're using Connectors to load the json data into a Kafka Topic using AVRO storage where key and values are coming in as STRUCT types,then it is very important that key's must be transformed/extracted to target types before joining. The connectors will not do transformation to your keys unless you specify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr: Your table data needs to be keyed on the column on which you're joining.**

Using the sample data above, here's how to investigate and fix.

1. Use KSQL to check the data in the topics (no need for `kafka-avro-console-consumer`). Format of the output data is timestamp, key, value

   - `stream`:

     ```
     ksql> print 'stream-test-topic' from beginning;
     Format:AVRO
     30/04/18 15:59:13 BST, null, {"DEAL_ID": "deal002", "DEAL_EXPENSE_CODE": "EXP002", "DEAL_BRANCH": "AMSTERDAM"}
     30/04/18 15:59:13 BST, null, {"DEAL_ID": "deal003", "DEAL_EXPENSE_CODE": "EXP003", "DEAL_BRANCH": "AMSTERDAM"}
     30/04/18 15:59:13 BST, null, {"DEAL_ID": "deal004", "DEAL_EXPENSE_CODE": "EXP004", "DEAL_BRANCH": "AMSTERDAM"}
     ```
   - `table`:

     ```
     ksql> print 'expense-test-topic' from beginning;
     Format:AVRO
     30/04/18 16:10:52 BST, pk1, {"EXPENSE_CODE": "EXP001", "EXPENSE_DESC": "Regulatory Deposit"}
     30/04/18 16:10:52 BST, pk2, {"EXPENSE_CODE": "EXP002", "EXPENSE_DESC": "ABC - Sofia"}
     30/04/18 16:10:52 BST, pk3, {"EXPENSE_CODE": "EXP003", "EXPENSE_DESC": "Apple Corporation"}
     30/04/18 16:10:52 BST, pk4, {"EXPENSE_CODE": "EXP004", "EXPENSE_DESC": "Confluent Europe"}
     30/04/18 16:10:52 BST, pk5, {"EXPENSE_CODE": "EXP005", "EXPENSE_DESC": "Air India"}
     30/04/18 16:10:52 BST, pk6, {"EXPENSE_CODE": "EXP006", "EXPENSE_DESC": "KLM International"}
     ```

   At this point, note that the key (`pk<x>`) does not match the column on which we will be joining
2. Register the two topics:

   ```
   ksql> CREATE STREAM deals WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='stream-test-topic', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');

    Message
   ----------------
    Stream created
   ----------------

   ksql> CREATE TABLE expense_codes_table WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='expense-test-topic', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO', KEY='EXPENSE_CODE');

    Message
   ---------------
    Table created
   ---------------
   ```
3. Tell KSQL to query events from the beginning of each topic

   ```
   ksql> SET 'auto.offset.reset' = 'earliest';
   Successfully changed local property 'auto.offset.reset' from 'null' to 'earliest'
   ```
4. Validate that the table's declared key per the DDL (`KEY='EXPENSE_CODE'`) matches the actual key of the underlying Kafka messages (available through the `ROWKEY` system column):

   ```
   ksql> SELECT ROWKEY, EXPENSE_CODE FROM expense_codes_table;
   pk1 | EXP001
   pk2 | EXP002
   pk3 | EXP003
   pk4 | EXP004
   pk5 | EXP005
   pk6 | EXP006
   ```

   **The keys don't match. Our join is doomed!**
5. Magic workaround—let's rekey the topic using KSQL!

   - Register the table's source topic as a KSQL *`STREAM`*:

     ```
     ksql> CREATE STREAM expense_codes_stream WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='expense-test-topic', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');

      Message
     ----------------
      Stream created
     ----------------
     ```
   - Create a derived stream, keyed on the correct colum. This is underpinned by a re-keyed Kafka topic.

     ```
     ksql> CREATE STREAM EXPENSE_CODES_REKEY AS SELECT * FROM expense_codes_stream PARTITION BY EXPENSE_CODE;

      Message
     ----------------------------
      Stream created and running
     ----------------------------
     ```
   - Re-register the KSQL `_TABLE_` on top of the re-keyed topic:

     ```
     ksql> DROP TABLE expense_codes_table;

      Message
     ----------------------------------------
      Source EXPENSE_CODES_TABLE was dropped
     ----------------------------------------
     ksql> CREATE TABLE expense_codes_table WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='EXPENSE_CODES_REKEY', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO', KEY='EXPENSE_CODE');

      Message
     ---------------
      Table created
     ---------------
     ```
   - Check the keys (declared vs message) match on the new table:

     ```
     ksql> SELECT ROWKEY, EXPENSE_CODE FROM expense_codes_table;
     EXP005 | EXP005
     EXP001 | EXP001
     EXP002 | EXP002
     EXP003 | EXP003
     EXP006 | EXP006
     EXP004 | EXP004
     ```
6. Successful join:

   ```
   ksql> SELECT D.DEAL_EXPENSE_CODE, E.EXPENSE_DESC \
   FROM deals D \
     LEFT JOIN expense_codes_table E \
     ON D.DEAL_EXPENSE_CODE = E.EXPENSE_CODE  \
   WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 3 MINUTE) \
   GROUP BY D.DEAL_EXPENSE_CODE, E.EXPENSE_DESC;

   EXP006 | KLM International
   EXP003 | Apple Corporation
   EXP002 | ABC - Sofia
   EXP004 | Confluent Europe
   EXP001 | Regulatory Deposit
   EXP005 | Air India
   ```

Comment: Thanks, @robin for answering this question. It was a blocker for us. I appreciate your time and effort to provide the solution. The solution works. 


Thanks again :)