# KSQL join returns null fields

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I am trying to join the following stream

```
 Field     | Type
---------------------------------------
 ROWTIME   | BIGINT           (system)
 ROWKEY    | VARCHAR(STRING)  (system)
 USER_ID   | VARCHAR(STRING)
 FIRSTNAME | VARCHAR(STRING)
---------------------------------------
```

with the following table:

```
 Field     | Type
---------------------------------------
 ROWTIME   | BIGINT           (system)
 ROWKEY    | VARCHAR(STRING)  (system)
 USER_ID   | VARCHAR(STRING)
 USERNAME  | VARCHAR(STRING)
---------------------------------------
```

using

```
SELECT M.USER_ID, \
       C.USERNAME \
FROM MY_STREAM M \
LEFT JOIN MY_TABLE C \
ON (M.USER_ID = C.USER_ID);
```

but `USERNAME` contains only `null` values.

```
1 | null
2 | null
3 | null
4 | null
5 | null
6 | null
7 | null
8 | null
```

I am sure that there are common `user_id`s and that no `username` is `null` in the table. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Perhaps you can check whether your experience matches https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020930/ksql-left-join-displays-columns-from-stream-but-not-tables.

Answer (score 2):

See my answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50102662/confluent-4-1-0-ksql-stream-table-join-table-data-null/50103660#50103660), in which I demonstrate how to troubleshoot joins like this.

In short, you need to key the messages in your table's topic on the column on which you join.

If you're going to join on `USER_ID` then :

`SELECT ROWKEY, USER_ID FROM MY_TABLE`

should return

```
1 | 1 
2 | 2
3 | 3
```

etc